# TK1, ROS and Kinect V2

Tags: ros, kinect, iai-kinect2, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

With the TK1 being a fairly well supported ROS platform, I was wondering how well the USB 3.0 port is supported?
Presumably, I would be using 14.04 and Indigo to get the ball rolling.

Specifically, how difficult should it be to get the Kinect V2 running on the TK1?
Austin might know about this.

Hopefully, we can get cheaper "starter" ROS platforms out there if this works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201614/tk1,-ros-and-kinect-v2/) by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe with the new [grinch kernel](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/795734/) for L4T 21.2.1 you shouldnt have a problem with usb3.0. Here is a [link](http://www.e-consystems.com/USB-3-Camera-on-JetsonTK1-kit.asp) where See3Cam (USB3.0) had some successes with the Jetson over USB 3.0, however in the link they are instructing to use L4T 19.3 which I read for most people did not work well. Also take a look on the elinux page for jetson for [known usb 3.0 cameras](http://elinux.org/Jetson/Cameras#USB_3.0_webcams_known_to_be_working) to work. Whether you know or not, make sure you turn off the USB autosuspend feature (you dont have to worry about this if you use the grinch kernel for r21.2.1 because its disabled by default).

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on 2015-01-26**:
Thanks, that looks like a great place to start!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't had any trouble using USB 2.0 devices, including the original Kinect, with the USB 3.0 port on the TK1 board.

I haven't tried the Kinect V2 with the TK1 board, and I haven't heard from anyone else who has. If the Linux drivers for the Kinect V2 work, it should probably be possible to get it working on the TK1.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on 2015-01-26**:
Thanks for letting me know, I will try it out in the coming weeks and answer here.
Cheers!